# how to copy xml nodes verbatim in xslt

Tags: xml, xslt

How can I simplify this XSLT where I mainly copy lots of XML nodes verbatim, where xxx stands for some uninteresting name:

```
<xsl:template match="xxx">
    <zzz>
        <wrapper1>
            <!-- verbatim copying of content of existing wrapper tag
                 which is a list of codes -->
            <xsl:for-each select="wrapper1/code">
              <code>
                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
              </code>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </wrapper1>
        <wrapper2>
            <!-- lots of verbatim copying of xml tags
                 to the added wrapper tag -->
            <city>
              <xsl:value-of select="city"/>
            </city>
            <state>
              <xsl:value-of select="state"/>
            </state>
            <postalCode>
              <xsl:value-of select="postalCode"/>
            </postalCode>
            <country>
              <xsl:value-of select="country"/>
            </country>
            <!-- etc etc -->
        </wrapper2>
    </zzz>
</xsl:template>
```

The purpose of this xslt is to convert xml like this:

```
<xxx>
  <wrapper1>
    <code>001</code>
    <!-- more codes may be present, hence xsl:for-each -->
  </wrapper1>
  <city>Amsterdam</city>
  <state>NH</state>
  <postalCode>1234AA</postalCode>
  <country>Holland</country>
</xxx>
```

to something similar but with the missing wrapper tag for address fields:

```
<xxx>
  <wrapper1>
    <code>001</code>
    <!-- more codes may be present, hence xsl:for-each -->
  </wrapper1>
  <wrapper2> <!-- wrapper added by xslt -->
    <city>Amsterdam</city>
    <state>NH</state>
    <postalCode>1234AA</postalCode>
    <country>Holland</country>
  </wrapper2>
</xxx>
```

and the purpose of all those wrapper tags is that it makes it possible to write an XSD schema that xsd.exe from the Microsoft SDK can use to create C# classes to nicely match the database table formats so that I do not have to write all those field names in C# classes.

I find xslt syntax tricky, and although I managed to get the above to actually work, I guess that there still are intelligent features in xslt to make things work better.

Comment: So how does you input XML look? Are you not aware of `<xsl:copy-of select="wrapper1/code"/>`? Do you know the identity transformation as the base for most XML to XML transformation where you want to copy some, change some and/or delete some stuff?

Comment: @MartinHonnen input xml added, and yes, I have heard of xsl:copy but googling on it I did not find something that helped me understand it to help in my problem. Also, a trick for wrapper1 would be nice, but a trick for fields like city, state etc is much more appreciated, because our tables have LOTS of fields

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you simply want

```
<xsl:template match="xxx">
    <zzz>
        <xsl:copy-of select="wrapper1"/>
        <wrapper2>
            <xsl:copy-of select="* except wrapper1"/>
        </wrapper2>
    </zzz>
</xsl:template>
```

`* except wrapper1` is XSLT/XPath 2 and later, in XSLT/XPath 1 you can use `*[not(self::wrapper1)]` instead.

As an alternative, start your XSLT approach with the identity transformation template

```
<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

which recursively copies nodes level by level and override it with templates for the change(s) you want e.g. in your case

```
<xsl:template match="xxx">
  <zzz>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="wrapper1"/>
    <wrapper2>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="*[not(self::wrapper1)]"/>
    </wrapper2>
  </zzz>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: I use Microsoft's XslCompiledTransform which is an XSLT 1.0 processor, but I will also try your XPath1 option. I guess the syntax will allow to exclude two wrappers for more complex input xml. I would also be happy with  for each field to be copied something like: xsl:copy-of select="country" , less sophisticated, but already much better than my original xslt

Comment: I really like your help and hope that I one time will reach the maturity to master and utilize xslt 2, and I upvoted your answer, but as a side note, I did not want to do any copy-to. If my colleagues in a country far away had just put in the wrapper elements themselves, I did not have to do any xslt at all. Using straight copy-to slashes 2/3 of my original code, and is also very easy to read and self-explanatory, so for this occasion I will stick with that.

Answer (score 0):

Although Martin's answer is more sophisticated, I am already very happy with this solution based on his explanation of copy-of:

```
<xsl:template match="xxx">
  <zzz>
    <xsl:copy-of select="wrapper1" />
    <wrapper2>
      <xsl:copy-of select="city" />
      <xsl:copy-of select="state" />
      <xsl:copy-of select="postalCode" />
      <xsl:copy-of select="country" />
    </wrapper2>
  </zzz>
</xsl:template>
```

With dozens of fields Martin's solution would be much better, but in reality I have something like 15 fields.

When using microsoft tools like C# xslt.transform, I'd better stick to the basic XSLT 1.0 features. Also, calling myself still an xml novice, this is easier to comprehend.

Anyway, thanks, Martin. +1